# JPA Query does not work

Tags: java, jpa

Can you help me please with this problem? I want use this method for find the specific nick in my database (It made with Apache Derby). I have used the EntityManager and mapping Persistence - Entity classes from database in the NetBeans.

```
public static boolean findByNick(String nick) {

    List<eng.db.User> ret;
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.nick =:nick");
    q.setParameter("nick", nick);
    ret = q.getResultList();
    em.close();

    boolean hodnota = false;

    if (ret.isEmpty()) {
        hodnota = true;
    }

    return hodnota;
}
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in      EntityManager:
>       Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.nick =:nick)].
>       [21, 21] A select statement must have a FROM clause.
>       [7, 7] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
>       [9, 20] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
>       [41, 42] The query contains a malformed ending.

Where is the problem please?

Comment: even if you use: "FROM User u WHERE u.nick =:nick" as the query ?

Comment: Where is the problem? That is not a valid JPQL query. There is no "*" in JPQL. Any basic JPA reference would tell you this

Answer (score 1):

If `nick` is the primary key of your entity (`@Id`), then use:

```
return em.find(eng.db.User, nick) != null;
```

Or if not:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT TRUE FROM User u WHERE u.nick =:nick");
q.setParameter("nick", nick);
return !q.getResultList().isEmpty();
```

By returning a simple boolean, you minimize the DB response.

Comment: Thanks, if I use your second output, I get this error:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "User" at line 1, column 15.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE (Nick = 'aaa')
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=User sql="SELECT ? FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)")

Comment: I suspect your underlying database has `User` as a reserved word.  Try changing the table name (use `@Table` annotation on the entity class).

Comment: Thanks, User is really reserved word. I have created the new project with name Userr. I have used this query: "SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM Userr WHERE (Nick = :nick)" and I get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM Userr WHERE (Nick = :nick)]. 
[41, 41] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration. Can you help me please?

Comment: That is not a JPA query.  Instead use: `SELECT u.UserID, u.EnterKey, u.Nick FROM Userr u WHERE u.Nick = :nick`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

UPDATE

according to your comment now the query should be:

```
SELECT u.userID, u.enterKey, u.nick 
FROM User u
WHERE u.nick = ?
```

or with named param

```
SELECT u.userId, u.enterKey, u.nick 
FROM User u
WHERE u.nick = :nick
```

where usereID, enterKey and nick are fields(properties) of your entity type User.

Your User class should look pretty much like this

```
@Entity
public class User {

      @Id
      private long userId;

     @column(name="EnterKey"
      private String enterKey;

      @column(name="nick")
      private String nick;

      // setter getter
}
```

Regard that this hql and you use the class and property names  of the object model which you defined as arguments for the query.

in your query Hibernate or any other JPA implementation creates  a list of objects of type User using the mapping you defined. The expression `*` can not be associated with an object name of this type. The equivalent to `*` in sql is in object related query languages just the of the alias of the from clause in your case "u" since the from clause looks like this:

```
From User u
```

If you want just to select separate fields of your Entity you have to declare

```
 Select alias.property
 from Entity alias
```

or in your special case

```
 Select u.nick
 From User u
```

In this case instances of type User are created and the field nick is set.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 9.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT  FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)
 bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=User sql="SELECT  FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)")

Comment: And if I use "u" I get this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT User u From User u Where u.nick = :nick]. 
[24, 25] The identification variable 'u' cannot be declared more than once.
[12, 13] The identification variable 'u' cannot be declared more than once.

Comment: Try simply: `from User u where u.nick = :nick`, without the select statement.

Comment: Put the u in bracket or just use the from clause without select statement as Laabidi Raaisi suggested

Comment: Thanks, but I get error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "User" at line 1, column 36.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)
 bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=User sql="SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)")

Comment: please try the exact code you mentioned in your question, just without "select *" and give us the result errors if any. Here you are using "?" in your query and we don't know how did you set the param value

Comment: So I use Query q = em.createQuery("from User u where u.nick = :nick"); and I call this method from servlet: if (!login.equals("") && !enterKey.equals("")) { result1 = eng.app.UserBO.findByNick(login);....
And I get error that I wrote above...

Comment: Pls show also your entity class either annotated or if not the hbm mapping  file.

Comment: @Christian Schack I used your output with named parameters and now I have error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u.userId, u.enterKey, u.nick FROM User u WHERE u.nick = :nick]. 
[7, 15] The state field path 'u.userId' cannot be resolved to a valid type. In automaticaly created java class I have this:
@Column(name = "UserID")
private Integer userID;

Comment: When I use "UserID" I get this error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "User" at line 1, column 36.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)
 bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=User sql="SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM User WHERE (Nick = ?)")

Comment: It must be the name of the property of your java class. So when your property is named userID it must be u.userID within your select clause. This is also case sensitive, so pay attention on that.

Comment: If I use Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM Userr WHERE (Nick = " + nick + ")"); I get this error: ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT UserID, EnterKey, Nick FROM Userr WHERE (Nick = :nick)]. 
[41, 41] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration. Can you help me please?